# Instrumental Variables in dynamic panels

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, estimation, panel-data, instrumental-variables

Most of the literature I have found on dynamic panels discuss difference GMM and system GMM estimators. See [here](http://fmwww.bc.edu/EC-C/S2013/823/EC823.S2013.nn05.slides.pdf) for a brief description of these estimators. However, I have been unable to find material on the use of exogenous instrumental variables in dynamic panels. Assume we are estimating the following model:

$\Delta Y_{i,t}=\alpha_i+\gamma_t+\beta_0Y_{i,t-1}+\beta_1B_{i,t}+\epsilon_{i,t}$ ,

and we have at our disposal an exogenous instrument(s) $V_{i,t}$ which we can use to instrument the variable of interest $B_{i,t}$ (we assume it meets the standard Pearl IV [conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variables_estimation)).

Two issues come to mind:

1. Autocorrelation of the error term
2. Autocorrelation of the instrumental variable(s)

My question is twofold, (i) do you see the above as concerns in the estimation of instrumental variables models in dynamic panels (using instrument $V_{i,t}$)? (i) what other issues should one keep in mind when estimating such model?